# How do I count distinct events over sequential seconds?

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

I have a database with multiple columns, date, timestamp (HH:MM:SS), and phone numbers. I am trying to find a way to find unique calls in sequential seconds. For Example:

```
Date          Timestamp     Phone_number
10-12-2019    15:15:23      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:15:23      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:15:24      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:15:24      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:15:25      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:20:21      111-111-1111
10-12-2019    15:20:21      111-111-1111
10-12-2019    15:20:22      111-111-1111
10-12-2019    15:22:33      999-999-9999
```

Ideally, I'd like to count the first 999-999-9999 as one call and 111-111-1111 as one call, and the second 999-999-9999 call as a call on the basis of the calls have the same timestamp or occurred in sequential seconds.

With an output similar to this with a count of 1 with the min(timestamp) of the non sequential call:

```
Date          Timestamp     Phone_number
10-12-2019    15:15:23      999-999-9999
10-12-2019    15:20:21      111-111-1111
10-12-2019    15:22:33      999-999-9999
```

I'm not entirely sure where to start. I believe I'd have to create a subselect of the time based on the previous second. Not sure how to implement it...or if it would hand timestamps with the same second

```
SELECT t1.time, t1.phone_number, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.x)
FROM myTable AS t1
JOIN myTable AS t2 ON t2.timestamp BETWEEN DATE_SUB(t1.timestamp, INTERVAL 1 second) AND t1.timestamp
GROUP BY t1.timestamp, t1.phone_number
```

I'm using MySql. Open to any help! Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you storing the date and timestamp in different columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8.0, this can be solved using window function `lag()`. You can recover the date/time of the previous call to the same number in a subquery, and then filter out records for which a previous call to the same number occured one second before:

```
select date, timestamp, phone_number
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        lag(concat(date, ' ', timestamp)) 
            over(partition by phone_number order by date, timestamp) lag_datetime
    from mytable t
) x
where 
    lag_datetime is null
    or concat(date, ' ', timestamp) > lag_datetime + interval 1 second
```

Note: storing date and time in separated columns is not a good idea, since it complicates the logic when you need to actually compare date/times.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qoTXGtSBM3FpRC8gyV7V3i/0)**:

```
| date       | timestamp | phone_number |
| ---------- | --------- | ------------ |
| 2019-10-12 | 15:15:23  | 999-999-9999 |
| 2019-10-12 | 15:20:21  | 111-111-1111 |
| 2019-10-12 | 15:22:33  | 999-999-9999 |
```

Comment: Great answer friend! I had no idea about the lag function. And I hear you about the date and time columns. Wasn't my data ;/ Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Welcome @scarebear!

Answer (score 1):

This is a complicated problem.  It is difficult because:

- You have the date/time columns in two columns.
- You have duplicate rows.
- Calls could span multiple days.

So, I think the best approach is a range partition after combining the date and time columns into a single column:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(phone_number) over (partition by phone_number
                                     order by timestamp(date, timestamp)
                                     range between 1 second preceding and current row
                                    ) as prev_phone_number
      from t
     ) t
where prev_phone_number is null or prev_phone_number <> phone_number;
```